# Error Objects in \usage without \alias in documentation object from R CMD Check

Tags: r, package, roxygen2

I have written a small package for my own use, and using devtools everything has gone very well. However, I tried to run R CMD Check on it, and got a number of errors, seemingly because my usage and examples use functions from base R that aren't in my package, for instance here's my minimal function, and roxygen documentation

```
#' Function to Sort a dataframe with a given list of columns
#' Cribbed from Spector, P. (2008). "Data Manipulation with R", UseR! Springer. Pg78
#' @param df Dataframe to be sorted
#' @param ... list of columns to sort on
#' @return A sorted dataframe
#' @author "Paul Hurley"
#' @export
#' @usage with(dataframe,sortframe(dataframe,column1, column2, column3))
#' @examples with(iris,sortframe(iris,Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,Petal.Length))
sortframe<-function(df,...){df[do.call(order,list(...)),]}
```

and R CMD Check gives

```
Undocumented arguments in documentation object 'sortframe'
  'dataframe' 'sortframe(dataframe, column1, column2, column3)'
Documented arguments not in \usage in documentation object 'sortframe':
  'df' '...'
Objects in \usage without \alias in documentation object 'sortframe':
  'with'
```

Is there a way to tell R CMD Check / roxygen2 that these functions are described in base ?

Comment: In my case, I removed `@name`, then the error vanished. https://github.com/r-lib/roxygen2/issues/695

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't include a `@usage` tag.  Roxygen will infer it from your code.  your `@usage` is really an example.  R is complaining because you are referring to objects that aren't in your function definition at all.  `@usage`, if you insist on putting it in yourself, should only reference `sortframe`, `df`, and `...`.  Since you already have an `@example`, you should be able to omit the `@usage` tag.